# Using PostgreSQL Spark-connector in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is it possible to work with the Postgres tables using Spark-connector? Write and read to a Yugabyte Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to read and write in YugabyteDB through the JDBC Spark connector. You can follow the Spark documentation as is.

Because YugabyteDB is PostgreSQL-compliant most PostgreSQL connectors should work just fine.